# combining element ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get both labels to appear but unfortunately only one of them is showing **#city_label**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showDiv(element, pro2) {
        if (pro2.children("option:selected").val() == 2) element.show();
        else element.hide();
    }
    var myElement = $("div#pro2");
    var mypro2 = $("select#ptype");

    $("select").change(function() {
        showDiv(myElement, mypro2)
    });

   $("#ctry").change(function() {
      $(".state").hide();

      var stateSelect = $("#state_" + $(this).val());

      if (stateSelect.length === 0)
         $("#state_label" && "#city_label").hide();
      else {
         $("#state_label" && "#city_label").show();
         stateSelect.show();
      }       
   });     
});
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<label id="state_label" style="display:none">State:</label><br />
<label id="city_label" style="display:none">Postal or City:</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's... not how `&&` works. In this case, it will return its right operand. What you want is this, using a comma in the selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showDiv(element, pro2) {
        if (pro2.children("option:selected").val() == 2) element.show();
        else element.hide();
    }
    var myElement = $("div#pro2");
    var mypro2 = $("select#ptype");

    $("select").change(function() {
        showDiv(myElement, mypro2)
    });

   $("#ctry").change(function() {
      $(".state").hide();

      var stateSelect = $("#state_" + $(this).val());

      if (stateSelect.length === 0)
         $("#state_label, #city_label").hide();
      else {
         $("#state_label, #city_label").show();
         stateSelect.show();
      }       
   });     
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `&&` operator the way you are, to select multiple elements at once you should include them in a single string separated by a comma; try this:

```
if (stateSelect.length === 0)
  $("#state_label,#city_label").hide();
else {
  $("#state_label,#city_label").show();
  stateSelect.show();
}
```